# Not getting most recent value for custom business metric from prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have a deployment on Kubernetes and it, for example runs on 3 pods.

There are some business related custom metrics which I want to export to prometheus.
Now the metrics are derived from a costly queries, so I do not run the query on each pod. instead I have created a job which invokes an API on a service which will be catered by any of the running pod.

Consider below scenario

```
Pod1: Recent data: metric1=300
Pod1: 2 hours old data: metric1=200
Pod1: 3 hours old data: metric1=500
```

Now the data important to me is from Pod1 but I am struggling to generate a prometheus query which will give me desired result.

I've tried the query below

`last_over_time(metric1{status="status1"}[$__interval])`

But it gives me result from all the pods.

I am quite a new to prometheus and grafana.

Comment: There is no trivial way to do it. If you can be reasonably sure, that metric _will_ change it's value after recalculation, _and_ job is run with equal time repetition, you can use something like `metric1 != metric1 offset 1h`, where 1h is time of job repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the labels option in prometheus queries for fine tuning your metrics. The {pod=”mypod”} label in the query definition helps in getting metrics for that particular pod. You can get more details on the same by going through this **[blog](https://www.opsramp.com/guides/prometheus-monitoring/promql/)**, below is the sample command taken from the blog to explain how to use pod labels.

```
 sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod="mypod"})
```

If you want to find the errors in the syntax or want to learn what these query returns use Promlens tool, it will explain what each block in the query returns and will be very useful for learning prometheus queries.